# New to Twilio and struggling to pass data from database to Twilio so it sends text message with information with a serverless function on Azure

Tags: javascript, azure, twilio

I only started using Twilio last week and am getting confused with how to set up my Twilio account so it can receive information from a database when a field changes and then text it to a number.

I have gone through the docs to set it up with node and can get the text message to be sent if I sent a text to my Twilio number, but getting the data from a different source is seeming a lot harder.

I'm using JavaScript with Windows Azure. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add the Twilio SDK to your Azure function, trigger the function when the database is updated, and use the SMS client to send a message when the function is triggered.

Here is a code sample for sending a simple message from the quickstart docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node):

```
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
const accountSid = 'AC0840e531a54515afbda482d80c48fb10';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
  .create({
     body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
     from: '+15017122661',
     to: '+15558675310'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
  .done();
```